# Insert data to Mysql getting slower and slower

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mariadb

I need to insert 388 datas per minute to local Database.
At first when the table is Empty, I only need 5 second to Insert to database.

But when the table gets larger, the program efficacy slow down to more than one minute when the amount of rows comes to 1,026,558.

And the useage of CPU is 100%. It's unusual.

here is my code:

```
public static void dataToDB(String[] routeIDArray,String[] levelArray,String[] valueArray,String[] travelTimeArray, int amountOfData)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
        String sqlCmd, updateSqlCmd = "UPDATE `datetimetable` SET ";
        for(int counter = 0; counter < amountOfData; counter++)
        {
            sqlCmd = "ALTER TABLE `datetimetable` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `" + routeIDArray[counter] + "` INT NULL;"
                + "INSERT INTO `roadvalue`.`data` (`level`,`value`,`traveltime`) VALUES ("
                + levelArray[counter] + ","
                + valueArray[counter] + ","
                + travelTimeArray[counter] + ");"
                + "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM `data`;";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, con);
            con.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();
            updateSqlCmd += "`" + routeIDArray[counter] + "` = " + rdr[0] + ",";
            rdr.Close();
        }
        updateSqlCmd = updateSqlCmd.TrimEnd(',');
        updateSqlCmd += " WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * WHERE dateTime = '" + dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00") + "');";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(updateSqlCmd, con);//update data key to datetimetable
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        con.Close();
    }
    public static void checkDateTimeExisted()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        String sqlCmd;
        sqlCmd = "INSERT INTO `datetimetable` (`dateTime`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '" + dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00")
                     + "') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT `dateTime` FROM `datetimetable` WHERE `dateTime` = '" + dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00") + "') LIMIT 1; ";

            con.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
    }
```

And Mysql Engine is InooDB, table "data" has one Auto_Increment Primary key, table "datetimetable" has an Auto_Increment Primary key and a not duplicate datetime as index.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: how many different values are there for `routeIDArray[counter]`? especially with large tables, altering them is a huge, huge, huge performance killer - you should try a different way of achieving whatever you're trying to achieve with this

Comment: I use Thread to run dataToDB(), every 50 datas run a thread.

Comment: so i understand right that instead of making your code threadsafe, you on-demand create one new column per thread? you could try running all your inserts in one thread, with no extra columns, with a prepared statement and inside a transaction. should give you a huge performance boost. oh: and open/clode your db-connection just once. that's a huge killer, too.

Comment: My first idea would be to insert all the data in one go (`insert into roadvalue.data(...) values (a,b,c),(a,b,d),(...)`), and then to update your `datetimetable` afterwards (you don't even need to prepare it, the data is in `roadvalue.data`, just join it. And just as a general rule: you do not want to add columns for new routeids. You want to change your datamodel to use them in rows.

Comment: I delete the alter command , but the efficacy still very slow.

Comment: I create datetimetable is for speed up search data. For example, I want to know in the time the road situation, I query datetime and routeID get the key of "data" table. And then get the data detil.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE roadvalue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer, the command "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM `data`;" should add LIMIT 1 or it will get all the ID kill the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ALTER TABLE` in a loop -- Plan ahead and provide all the columns before starting.

Do not use multiple statements in a single string.  This has security implications, etc.

Do not use `WHERE EXISTS...` when (I think) a simple `WHERE` would work.

If there is `UNIQUE(datetime)`, then the final `INSERT` can be simply

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO datetimetable
    (datetime)
    VALUE
    ('...');
```

Do batch inserts unless you need the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  `LIMIT 1` should not be necessary.

Do not 'Normalize' datetime values; it only slows things down.  Just put the datetime as is in the main table.